# SELECT * FROM msql

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите можно сделать выборку на уровни запроса например мне нужно вывести все значения которые будут иметь такой вид PO-01202-1454
`SELECT model FROM` и выводились только значения такого вида  PO-01202-1454 цифры разные `PO-` не именное. Или это нужно делать уже с полученными данными ?

Comment: Это значение лежит в поле БД или как-то формируется? Что такое "не именное."?

Comment: Это значения находится в поле бд в таком виде `PO-2015-0241`

Comment: я, честно сказать, сути вопроса не понял.

Comment: Есть таблица с данными например `product` в ней есть поле `code` в этом поле есть записи такого вида `1020-0245` и такого `PO-0214-2541` Можно написать запрос так что бы выводились только значения такого вида `1020-2544` ?

Comment: Нашел решения `SELECT * FROM product WHERE code NOT REGEXP '^P+O'`

Comment: `not like 'PO%'` будет достаточно, не нужны тут регэксы. и индекс по полю сделайте, если данных прилично.

Comment: Я тоже смотрел в эту сторону но совсем забыл про `%` и начал делать not like 'PO' и не получилось вот посмотрел в сторону `REGEXP`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь